# vba speed up writing formular to cell matrix

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a matrix that is written to the sheet

```
Destination.Resize(UBound(Matrix, 2), UBound(Matrix, 1)).value = Application.Transpose(Matrix)
```

In this cells I want to replace every value 0 with NaN (not a number)

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each c In Destination.Cells
    If c.value = 0 Then
        c.FormulaLocal = "=NV()"
    End If
Next
```

this however takes very long.

Any possibility to make this faster?

Comment: have you considered using an autofilter?

Comment: Along with Application.ScreenUpdating = False, also try Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual (just remember to switch it back to xlCalculationAutomatic or whatever else it was previously set to at the end)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your NV() a typo or a UDF?  I used NA() in my example below as NV() does not exist in Excel 2007.  Assuming your code somewhere sets Destination to the complete relevant range (not done in the code above where you are using Resize, try:

**EDIT** lookat:= parameter added.

```
Destination.Replace what:=0, replacement:="=NA()", lookat:=xlWhole
```

Since you are adding multiple formulas, and not constants, you should also make the change suggested by **Dave** with regard to Calculation Mode.  And there are other things that could also be "turned off" if necessary -- e.g:  DisplayEvents, EnableEvents, Intgeractive, StatusBar

Comment: In english I assume it means "not available", which in german is "nicht verfügbar", thus NV. I find the english NaN (in Matlab) much clearer.

Comment: the problem with this code is , that is replaces on a string not a number basis. that means the number 200 is replaced by `2=NA()=NA()`. Also it replaces only in the first column. all others are skipped.

Comment: @MatthiasPospiech Understand about the NV() german vs english. Thanks.  With regard to replacing 200 with 2=NA()=NA(), merely specify the argument **lookat:=xlWhole** (I'll make that change in my answer).  With regard to only working in the first column, either you have not specified Destination to include other columns, or there are no 0's in your data.  I suggest placing a breakpoint on the Replace line, and then, in the immediate window, type ?Destination.Address to see what it is referring to.

Comment: I was wrong. VBA needs the english formula so that it appears correct in german. Adding "=NV()" results in #name?, whereas "=NA()" results in "=NV()". I had solved this by using `c.FormulaLocal = "=NV()"`. If that can be done also using the replace function that would be great, but not necessary. The thing with columns was wired. In the first run it did not work in future ones it worked on the whole table.

Comment: @MatthiasPospiech I would think that using "=NV()" in the Range.Replace method would work on your system.  Try it and let me know. But the Replace method should certainly be faster than cycling through all the cells.